# Fine-tuning pre-trained Word2Vec model with Gensim 4.0

Tags: word2vec, transfer-learning, gensim, pretraining

With Gensim < 4.0, we can retrain a word2vec model using the following code:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
model.train(my_corpus, total_examples=len(my_corpus), epochs=model.epochs)
```

However, what I understand is that Gensim 4.0 is no longer supporting `Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format`. Instead, I can only load the keyedVectors.

How to fine-tune a pre-trained word2vec model (such as the model trained on GoogleNews) with my domain-specific corpus using Gensim 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to fine-tune on your domain-specific corpus using Gensim 4.0:

1. Create a Word2Vec model with the same vector size as the pretrained model

   ```
   w2vModel = Word2Vec(vector_size=..., min_count=..., ...)
   ```
2. Build the vocabulary for the new corpus

   ```
   w2vModel.build_vocab(my_corpus)
   ```
3. Create a vector of ones that determine the mutability of the pretrained vectors. In the previous Gensim versions, this used to be a single `lockf` argument to the `intersect_word2vec_format` function. Using a vector of ones ensures that all the words in the vocabulary are updated during fine-tuning

   ```
   w2vModel.wv.vectors_lockf = np.ones(len(w2vModel.wv))
   ```
4. Perform a vocabulary intersection using `intersect_word2vec_format` function to initialize the new embeddings with the pretrained embeddings for the words that are in the pretraining vocabulary.

   ```
   w2vModel.wv.intersect_word2vec_format('pretrained.bin', binary=True)
   ```

   I am quoting from the official Gensim documentation as follows
   `intersect_word2vec_format` ([1])(https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html):

   > Merge in an input-hidden weight matrix loaded from the original C
   > word2vec-tool format, where it intersects with the current vocabulary.
   >
   > No words are added to the existing vocabulary, but intersecting words
   > adopt the file’s weights, and non-intersecting words are left alone.
5. Now, you can train the model on the new corpus

   ```
   w2vModel.train(my_corpus, total_examples=len(my_corpus), epochs=...)
   ```