# building embeddings for Phrases from scratch

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, bert, terminology, document-term-matrix

I have a datadet with many phrases which I would like to embed them from scratch. I dont want the cosine of the words in order to get a phrase embedding, this is because the phrases may appear in a different enviroment and I want to embed the two words together, or the tree words together in their own envoroment.

Is this possible?

If yes how exactly?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways word-embeddings are trained, however most of them require a ton of data. They usually involve learning vector representations that are useful for some self-supervised objective, which all tend to be pretty data-hungry.

- word2vec (and variants) learn representations by training a model to use those representations to predict adjacent words
- Approaches like ELMo and BERT use intermediate representations from a language model, which are pretrained on large text corpora

If you have a large enough dataset you *could* train new domain-specific embeddings from scratch, but it probably be more effective and much easier to finetune existing embeddings (i.e., initialize on models/representations and train on your domain data).

See: [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97568/fine-tuning-pre-trained-word2vec-model-with-gensim-4-0) for finetuning word2vec, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to train on phrases, then you will have to devise your tokenizer that way.
Pseudo code will look like:

```
 1. Write tokenizer that maps phrases to a single token  
 2. Using tokenizer generate vocabulary from text corpus
   a. this will assign multi word phrase a single token. for example the phrase "Natural language Processing" will be considered as one token.
 3. Once you have devised tokenizer that way, the remaining process will look same.
```

For example if you are training using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#training-your-own-model),
Following line will use your custom tokenizer instead of default gensim function.

```
yield utils.simple_preprocess(line)
```